# Android: positioning children in GridLayout

Tags: java, android, grid-layout

What is the method used to change the position of a children inside a GridLayout? (i.e. moving a view that is in (row 1, column 1) to (row 3, column 4)

Comment: You need to move the elements in the adapter used by the `GridLayout`. Do  you want to swap the elements in these two locations?

Comment: I'm not using an adapter, They're not swaping, when I move a view from (1,1) to (3,3) I want the view that was in (3,3) to move one position back, and the views before aswell

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up a `GridView` with a `GridLayout`. A `GridLayout` does not use an `Adapter` as you mentioned.